# .net http webclient to nodejs server. How to access data?

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, http

I have a .net c# client software that sends data like this:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string serialisedData = "";
    serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.UserData.Username, config.UserData.Password);
    byte[] responsebyte = client.UploadData(config.ServerAddress, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialisedData));
}
```

In nodejs, I currently have this kind of https setup:

```
_server = https.createServer({
            key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\bin\\cert\\${_config.sslkey}`, "utf8"),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}\\bin\\cert\\${_config.sslcert}`, "utf8")
        }, _listener);
_server.listen(_config.port, "0.0.0.0");

function _listener(req, res) {
    let data = []
    req.on('data', chunk => {
        data.push(chunk)
    })
    req.on('end', () => {
        JSON.parse(data)
    })
}
```

Now my problem. I cant get any data of the req or res object. Both "on" functionts dont fire and I dont know what to do now. Whats the right way to do this in NodeJS? (c# Code cant be changed)

---

Edit:
Here is the c# Server Code that works. How can I translate that into nodejs?

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add($"https://+:{Config.Port}/");
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
listener.Start();
for (; ; )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(DoWork), listener);
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    result = null;
}

private void DoWork(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(asyncResult);
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;


    string data;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding))
    {
        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    ....
    More Code
    ....

    string responseSerial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData);
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseSerial);
    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

    System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    output.Close();
}
```

Comment: Use HttpClient, not WebClient. What you try to do is an `HttpClient.PostAsync` call with a JSON string as payload, specifically a StringContent. There's no reason to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. WebClient is obsolete since 2012

Comment: Ok but I cant change the client software anymore, only the server software. But it must still be possible to get the data right?

Comment: `c# Code cant be changed` well, it has to. As for what's wrong, you'll have to use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually being sent to the server. Perhaps Node doesn't like the missing content type. It should be `application/json`. The content should be a POST request whose body is the JSON string

Comment: Thats bad. I will try to use Fiddler and look If I find something. It's funny that a c# server can get the data without problems but not a nodejs Server :)

Comment: You need an object on the server like a textbox, listbox, database, property that you can read and get the data back.

Comment: @jdweng What exactly do you mean by that? Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you want to read back data you have to read it from an object or variable.  You cannot upload data to empty space (Vaporware).  Once the data is stored you can read it.  You cannot read data from nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack `res.end()` somewhere to let node's server know that it should send response back. Before that you can write your actual response. Tested that on your exact C# code and a simplified version of the node server:

```
var http = require('http');

var _server = http.createServer(_listener);
_server.listen(1234);

console.log( 'started' );

function _listener(req, res) {
  let data = []
  req.on('data', chunk => {
    data.push(chunk)
  })
  req.on('end', () => {
    JSON.parse(data);
    res.write('response')
    res.end()
  })
}
```

Comment: Just something more. Any idea how to get the username and password from the credentials? In c# I had the Identity object but what do I need to do in nodejs?

Comment: @LastChar23: I'd start looking from the `req.headers` where headers sent by the client are present. Your C# client will most probably send the [basic auth header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).